# Looking for a branchless algorithm for converting a specific set of 4-bit integers

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I have 2 sets of possible 4-bit integers.
They are present in 2 columns.
There are exactly 6 differences between them (see `diff: [...]`):

```
0000 0000 diff: []
0101 0001 diff: [2]
1000 0010 diff: [3, 1]
0011 0011 diff: []
0110 0100 diff: [1]
0100 0101 diff: [0]
0111 0110 diff: [0]
```

I must only use arithmetic(additive) and bitwise operators: `+`,`-`,`>>`,`<<`,`|`,`&`,`^` to convert left/1st column to the one to the right/2nd one (input is an integer from the first column, should be converted to corresponding one from right) and can't figure out how to do it.

I tried using modulo and addition, all combinations of these two in terms of 4 bits were tried and the above variation is the best I got.

Comment: You could brute force all possibilities of logical operations `and, or, xor, ...` (combined with not) and hope you find one that gives the wanted result.

Comment: It is strange that you number bits from left to right. Just to be sure: 0101 represents the value 5, right?

Comment: Yes, 0101 represents 5, idk why I numbered them this way. Imma change the question rq

Comment: I used your old numbering, but principle is the same

Comment: To avoid misinterpretation, could you list *all* possible operators that can be used? Like `+`,`-`,`>>`,`<<`,`|`,`&`,`^`?

Comment: (+ state whether constants are allowed) Does *right column* refer to the 2nd or 3rd one?

Comment: trincot, you listed all allowed operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for instance use this expression, where `a` is the value in the first column:

```
((((a+2)&4)|(((a|4)+1)&8))>>2)|(((a^2)+1)&4)
```

I exaggerated the use of parentheses, but if the operands have the following precedence order (from high to low): `+`, `>>` `&`, `^`, `|` (as is the case in [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table), [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php),... etc), then this expression is equivalent:

```
(a+2&4|((a|4)+1&8))>>2|(a^2)+1&4
```

I suppose there are shorter ways to do it than that, but as this is not [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), I won't look any further.

Just a snippet to test it in JavaScript:

```js
const translate = (a) => (a+2&4|((a|4)+1&8))>>2|(a^2)+1&4;

const bin = a => a.toString(2).padStart(4, "0");

for (const a of [0b0000, 0b0101, 0b1000, 0b0011, 0b0110, 0b0100, 0b111]) {
    console.log(bin(a), "->", bin(translate(a)));
}
```

Comment: I'm curious about how did you come up with this

Comment: I looked at producing one bit at a time, and then combined those with `|`, and reworked the result a bit.

Comment: Currently I am testing your solution, so far so good

Comment: used your expression in my c code, it worked!

Comment: Great. I've upvoted Matt's answer, as it is quite elegant for this size of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

All the outputs fit into 3 bits, and all the inputs are from 0 to 8, so you can do this with a bit-packed lookup table:

`y = (47240704 >> (x*3))&7`

Comment: @Юрыч, as you just confirmed the set of operators and `*` was not in it, please realise that `(x*3)` can be replaced with `(x+x+x)` in this answer. It is quite elegant.

Comment: Suggest `0264153000`

Comment: @greybeard I thought about it, but I don't think the octal prefix is universally known.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option, not following the "integer as lookup table" trick (which is good though):

```
int t = n | 0xBC;
int s = (n + 0x4E) + t;
return s + (t ^ (s >> 2)) & 7;
```

The variables for reused values are not strictly necessary but reduce the number of operations. I don't count the assignments since they should not correspond to any explicit operation, but if you disagree with their presence you can factor that out.

This solution was found using a SAT solver.

Comment: thank you for your knowledge, its an interesting one